# create a calendar event for a whole team ( participants) using the graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, outlook-calendar

Is it possible to create a calendar event for a whole team using the graph api? Right now, the calendar is coming only in the logged in/organizer account through which the event/meeting is being created But, I want to have this feature for every users/attendees/participants in their calendars. If it is not possible, then, can a separate meeting invite be sent to every users in the attendees list to accept the event/meeting so that they can be notified about the event which has been created and which they need to attend.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Microsoft 365 group of users and use below API to create event.

POST /groups/{id}/calendar/events

**The calendar can be one for a user, or the default calendar of a Microsoft 365 group.**

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http